# Training custom-made CNN model in eager execution programming environment

Tags: tensorflow, keras, eager-execution

I have built CNN model by using the principle of "Model Sublclassing" in Keras. Here is the class which represents my model:

```
class ConvNet(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, data_format, classes):

        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()

        if data_format == "channels_first":
            axis = 1
        elif data_format == "channels_last":
            axis = -1

        self.conv_layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3,strides = (1,1),
                                                  padding = "same",activation = "relu")
        self.pool_layer1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2))
        self.conv_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3,strides = (1,1),
                                                  padding = "same",activation = "relu")
        self.pool_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2))
        self.conv_layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5,strides = (1,1),
                                                  padding = "same",activation = "relu")
        self.pool_layer3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (1,1),
                                                       padding = "same")
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dense_layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 512, activation = "relu")
        self.dense_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = classes, activation = "softmax")

    def call(self, inputs, training = True):

        output_tensor = self.conv_layer1(inputs)
        output_tensor = self.pool_layer1(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.conv_layer2(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.pool_layer2(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.conv_layer3(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.pool_layer3(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.flatten(output_tensor)
        output_tensor = self.dense_layer1(output_tensor)

        return self.dense_layer2(output_tensor)
```

I would like to know how to train it "eagerly", and by that I mean avoiding the use of `compile` and `fit` methods.

I am not sure how to exactly construct the training loop. I understand that I must perform `tf.GradientTape.gradient()` function in order to calculate the gradients and then use `optimizers.apply_gradients()` in order to update my model parameters.

What I do not understand is how can I make predictions with my model in order to get `logits` and then use them to calculate the loss. If someone could help me with the idea of how to construct the training loop I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager execution is the imperative programming mode to let developers follow Python's natural control flow. Essentially, you wouldn't need to first create placeholders, computational graphs and then execute them in TensorFlow sessions. You can use automatic differentiation to compute gradients in your training loop:

```py
for i in range(iterations):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(batch_examples, training = True)
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(batch_labels, logits)
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  opt.apply_gradients([grads, model.trainable_variables])
```

This is assuming that the `model` is of the class `Model` from Keras. I hope this solves your problem! You should also check out the [TensorFlow Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) on Eager Execution.